# What is the correct way to generate an index?

Tags: best-practices, indexing

For creating an index I am currently including

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

[...] \index{...} [...]

\printindex
```

into the document (and run `makeindex` inbetween compilations). I was told some time ago that this is the way to create indexes.

So, I'm wondering whether there is some more modern and flexible way to do this (similar to have BibLaTeX is a modern replacement for BibTeX). In particular, are there ways to add some styling options to the `\printindex` call. Currently I'd have to create an index style file or patch `theindex` just to remove `\MakeUppercase` from `\markboth` for the index.

If it matters, I usually use the KOMA-Script classes.

Answer (score 7):

The `imakeidx` package will call `makeindex` (or `xindy`, or other index compilers) in the LaTeX compilation, provided you call LaTeX with `-shell-escape`. It also allows you to pass options to `\makeindex`.

As for styling, you can use `.ist` files and pass them as argument (`-s` flag) to `makeindex` (or as an option to `\makeindex` if you use `imakeidx`).

The possible fields you can put in the `.ist` file are described [in the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/makeindex). It cannot do everything though. In my case, I had to play with sed between two LaTeX call (I know, shame on me) to get the results I wanted.

Here is a sample `.ist` file I'm using:

```
% Dotfill style
delim_0 "\\dotfill "
delim_1 "\\dotfill "
delim_2 "\\dotfill "
% M-dash style
%delim_0 "\\ocadr"
%delim_1 "\\ocadr "
%delim_2 "\\ocadr "

% Force subitems to be raggedleft when they overflow the line
% and make sure to keep items raggedright    
item_0 "\n  \\item\\raggedright"
item_1 "\n    \\subitem\\raggedleft"

% When using Old/New Testament parts in index
% Make them scshape
preamble "\\begin{multicols}{2}
\\makeatletter
\\let\\item\\@idxitem\\scshape
\\makeatother"
postamble "\\end{multicols}"
```

As you can see, you can already do a lot of things with that.

As mentioned by Thorsten, you can also use the `idxlayout` package, which controls some other parameters (such as paragraph lenghts, column lengths, etc.). Both `imakeidx` and `idxlayout` and compatible with Koma-Script classes (I'm using `imakeidx` with `scrbook`) and with each other.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like the [idxlayout](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package. It does not work like [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), but it may be a good point to start.